# App don't receive valid GPS updates using the GPS provider

Tags: java, android, gps, location

I get empty NMEA messages and `onLocationChanged(Location)` is never called when requesting gps coordinates. It only works when requesting via the network provider but then I get an accuracy of 2000 meters, same with fused provider.

This is my activity:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.GpsStatus;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.location.OnNmeaMessageListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener, OnNmeaMessageListener, ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    Context context;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = this;
        check_permission();
        start_gps_manager();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int i, @NonNull String[] strings, @NonNull int[] ints) {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void check_permission() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            String[] PERMISSIONS = {android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, 112);
        }
    }

    LocationManager gpsLocationManager;

    private void start_gps_manager() {
        gpsLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        Log.e(TAG, "Requesting GPS location updates");
        // gps satellite based
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        gpsLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, this);
        gpsLocationManager.addNmeaListener(this);
    }

    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        Log.e(TAG, latitude + " - " + longitude);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNmeaMessage(String s, long l) {
        Log.e(String.valueOf(l), s);
    }
}
```

And part of the AndroidManifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

The NMEA messages don't contain gps nor time data. How can I resolve this issue and get accurate gps coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes across the same issue in the future: GPS needs to acquire a fix before the application can receive valid gps coordinates. This takes some time depending on how good of a connection the gps module has to the gps satellites. This means that you'll have to wait until you are able to acquire gps coordinates.